# Brownian Motion and MonteCarlo Simulation

Tags: numerical-methods

While studying Random Numbers, I have come across brownian motion. In the text I am using (Numerical Analysis by Sauer); there is an example (chapter 9, example 9.9) where the author illustrates how a monte carlo simulation is used to estimate the escape time for a random walk escaping the interval [-3,6].

The expected value is ab = 18 and the author provides the following table:-

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\text{n} & \text{average escape time} & \text{error}\\
100 & 18.84 & 0.84 \\
200 & 17.47 & 0.53 \\
400 & 19.64 & 1.64 \\
800 & 18.53 & 0.53 \\
1600 & 18.27 & 0.27 \\
3200 & 18.16 & 0.16 \\
6400 & 18.05 & 0.05
\end{array}
$$

Am totally lost as to how the average escape times are calculated given monte carlo simulaion is used. Do I use an LCG? Can someone help advise? Please note that the previous example arrives at top exits and probabilities and am completely lost on how the book does it!

Comment: Do you know any R? Or Matlab?

Comment: yes I do know Matlab...

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  Are you asking how he generates random numbers; how he uses a sequence of random numbers to simulate brownian motion; or how he calculates the escape times?

Comment: I am not clear on how he generates the random numbers, how he simulates the brownian motion and how he calculates the escape times....am just totally lost....I need to see a full worked example; I do however know how to generate pseudo random numbers

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in Google Spreadsheets (recently upgraded, with much better performance). Here is how it looks   (explanation below):

[image: spreadsheet with random walk]

The column B is filled with zeroes, initial position. The time axis is horizontal, from left to right. Each entry in columns C,D,E,...  is a conditional statement based on its neighbor to the left (preceding state of the walk). If the walk reached the border, the statement prints "stop". If it did not, then a coin is tossed with `RAND()` function, and a step is made to the left `-1` or to the right `+1`.  The process repeats. The command shown on the screenshot is in cell G37:

```
=IF(F37<=-3,"stop",IF(F37>=6,"stop",IF(RAND()<0.5,F37-1,F37+1)))
```

Column A counts the number of steps made before the stop: this is just the number of the numerical entrie in columns to the right of B. The command in A37 is

```
=COUNT(C37:AX37)
```

(I figured that going to AX is enough for most walk instances to stop, but the spreadsheet could have been larger.)

Each of 50 rows is a path random walk. The average number of steps in this example turned out to be  18.08.

Of course, in Matlab etc you would use some kind of  `while` loop for each path of the walk, and `for` loop to average over some number of oaths.